# 404 error when trying to run PHP application on Glassfish 3.1.1 through Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, glassfish-3, php-5.3

While there are some similar posts about this issue, none seem to fit my problem exactly, so I would like to ask if anyone knows what I am doing wrong.

I am trying to run a PHP web application that I created in Netbeans. I am using Glassfish 3.1.1 as the web server. Whenever I run the application through Netbeans (by selecting the project, right clicking to get the context menu, then selecting "Run"), my browser opens to what I believe to be the correct url, but all I get is a 404 error page stating the following:

type: Status report

message:

description:The requested resource () is not available.

Am I missing some crucial configuration step?
I have checked my hosts file and it contains the entry:
127.0.0.1 localhost

Is there something else I need to do?
I have PHP 5.3.8 installed and all php commands run from the command line.
Would it be something in the php.ini file that needs to be configured?

I am stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

ANSWERED

Please accept the comment below from Jonathan Spooner as the correct answer.

Comment: GlassFish is a Java application server. You'll want to install a web server like Apache instead.

Comment: OK, thanks Jonathan. I figured that might be the case, since I had a Java web app running on it just fine, but couldn't get my php app working. I also have Apache Tomcat 6.0 installed on the machine, so I will try running it through there. If that brings up more questions, they will have to be in a new thread as they will pertain to Apache Tomcat config instead of Glassfish

Comment: Tomcat is also a Java application server. I've posted an answer that may help you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in the comments, GlassFish and Apache Tomcat are Java application servers. In order to serve PHP pages you'll need to install a web server such as [Apache HTTP](http://httpd.apache.org/) web server. You'll also need to configure Apache to serve PHP files.

Something that you might look into is [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) (Windows/Apache/MySql/PHP). This offers a simple way to get up and running quickly with little to no configuration.

Comment: Thanks again Jonathan. I am going to try again using WAMP.

Answer (score 3):

Just install `Quercus` within `GlassFish 3.x` and you can run `PHP` and `Java`.